# i would like to showing additional information of product between price and add to cart in wordpress WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, product

i would like to showing additional information of product between price and add to cart in wordpress WooCommerce

You can see the products with their title below:[image]

Website link: https://asiatic.endroid1.com/product/modern

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by adding an action to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook:

```
function show_additional_information() {
    global $product;

    do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_additional_information', 25 );
```

The `25` sets the priority when the custom action should be called.
In this case 25 is between the excerpt (and the price, which is above excerpt), and the add to cart button. As [noted in the source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-single-product.php):

```
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```